# Time Stamping Linux Hardware Interrupts

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, interrupt

I am interested in time stamping the receive times for various hardware signals(I2C,  UART, etc). From what I have read linux does not do this automatically.

Is there a way to modify the I2C and UART drivers to generate a system time-stamp or transfer the data to a shared memory location with a program in user space and append a timestamp to it?

Thanks

Comment: Seems like a [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/).  Are you referring to "packets" (whatever that might mean for UART) or individual bytes?  When DMA is utililized, there are typically fewer interrupts generated by devices such as UART and I2C controller.

Comment: Time stamping each byte would be fine, conceptually I am interested in start/stops of packets indicated with specific data sequences.

Comment: No need to modify anything! Use ftrace and perf tool.

Comment: Please explain!